# How to set a condition filter on a string type field of a table?

Tags: database-design, dolphindb

The content of the table is as follows:

```py
id = 0..4
tag = `FB`IBM`FB`IBM`AMZN
t =table(id, tag)
```

| id | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | FB |
| 1 | IBM |
| 2 | FB |
| 3 | IBM |
| 4 | AMZN |

The schema of the table is as below:

```py
t.schema().colDefs
```

| name | typeString | typeInt | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | INT | 4 |  |
| Tag | STRING | 8 |  |

I want to filter the tag fields which contain “IBM”, how to write the SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

Using the regexFind function , an example is as follows:

```py
select * from t where regexFind(tag, `IBM) != -1
```

result:

| id | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IBM |
| 3 | IBM |